# How to add async callbacks in node to a function call?

Tags: node.js

Question is too broad / unclear. Anyone interested in this answer would be better served by visiting: [Creating Callbacks for required modules in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382186/creating-callbacks-for-required-modules-in-node-js)

Basically I have included a CLI package in my node application. I need the CLI to spin up a new project (this entails creating a folder for the project). After the project folder is created, I need to create some files in the folder (using fs writeFile). The problem is right now, my writeFile function executes BEFORE the folder is created by the CLI package (This is detected by my console.log. This brings me to main main question.

Can I add an async callback function to the CLI.new without modifying the package I included?

```
  FoundationCLI.new(null, {
    framework: 'sites', // 'apps' or 'emails' also
    template: 'basic', // 'advanced' also
    name: projectName,
    directory: $scope.settings.path.join("")
  });

  try{
    if (!fs.existsSync(path)){
      console.log("DIRECTORY NOT THERE!!!!!");
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(correctedPath, JSON.stringify(project) , 'utf-8');
  } catch(err) {
    throw err;
  }
```

It uses foundation-cli. The new command executes the following async series. I'd love to add a callback to the package - still not quite sure how.

async.series(tasks, finish);

Anyone interested in this can probably get mileage out of:

[Creating Callbacks for required modules in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382186/creating-callbacks-for-required-modules-in-node-js)

Comment: do the CLI docs mention a completion callback?

Comment: They don't mention a completion callback. I am willing to modify the package to add this functionality, but I feel like I showed up to a final for a class I never showed up too.

Comment: What is `CLI` here? It's impossible to know what that can do unless you're more specific. If you can edit it, why not add in a callback argument? It's worth noting that [promises](https://www.promisejs.org) are often easier to work with, you can just chain things together: `CLI.new(...).then(...).then(...)`

Comment: Can you link to the module you're using for `CLI`? The seemingly obvious [`cli` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli) doesn't appear to be what you're using.

Comment: [`foundation-cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foundation-cli) doesn't appear to be intended for use as an API, only as a command. You could possibly [submit an issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli/issues) asking for the option of providing a callback.

Comment: tadman - the .then seems to be EXACTLY what I need. The only problem is that using .then throws an error! TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: @CodeManiak The error is because `.new()` doesn't `return` anything. Promises can be useful, but have to be supported by the API you're using. And, `foundation-cli` doesn't use/support them.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. I will be learning more about promises and callbacks so that I can patch the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the `new` command seem to be available on https://github.com/zurb/foundation-cli/blob/master/lib/commands/new.js

this code was not written to allow programmatic usage of the `new` command (it uses console.log everywhere) and does not call any callback when the work is finished.

so no there is no way to use this package to do what you are looking for. Either patch the package or find another way to do what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm totally up for patching the package. It doesn't seem overly complex given that the 'finish' method gets called by the CLI after it finishes.     
`async.series(tasks, finish);`. My question is.... where can I learn about the code I need to use to do this.... I imagine a signal being broadcasted by the "finish" method that I then catch with a signal handler in my code. Problem is I don't know how to do this with node. Only with C!

Comment: I don't know what you are looking for. If you need to automate tasks to setup a project or an environment, look into `grunt` or `gulp`. foundation-cli maybe is not a good starting point for your project