# avoiding while loop when checking if file exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, asynchronous

I have a node application that reads an uploaded file like so:

```
router.route('/moduleUpload')
    .post(function (request, response) {
        request.files.file.originalname = request.files.file.originalname.replace(/ +?/g, '');
        var media = new Media(request.files.file, './user_resources/module/' + request.body.module_id + '/');
        if (!fs.existsSync(media.targetDir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(media.targetDir, 0777, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    response.send("ERROR! Can't make the directory! \n");    // echo the result back
                }
            });
            fs.chmodSync(media.targetDir, 0777);

        }
        moveFile(media);
        var token = jwt.encode({
            mediaObject: media
        }, require('../secret')());
        response.status(200).json(token);

    });
```

Now when this file is uploaded and status code 200 is recieved my system then calls the following route:

```
router.route('/resourcePath/:encodedString')
    .all(function (req, res) {
        var decoded = jwt.decode(req.params.encodedString, require('../secret')());
        var mediaObject = decoded.mediaObject;
        var ext = mediaObject.file.originalname.substr(mediaObject.file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'));
        var path = 'app_server' + mediaObject.targetDir.substring(1) + mediaObject.fileName + ext;
        var fileExist = false;


        res.status(200).send(path)
    });
```

Now for some reason this call is being called before the file is correctly in place which results in that sometimes my users cannot see the content.

To make sure the file was in the folder i thought of the following code to add:

```
            var fileExist = false;

        while (!fileExist) {
            if (fs.existsSync('/var/www/learningbankapp/'+path)) {
                fileExist = true;
            }
        }
```

However im not sure that this a good solution namly because it goes against node.js nature. So my question is, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You could try it by making [your own callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382186/creating-callbacks-for-required-modules-in-node-js).

Comment: Looking at the fs api, there is this fs watcher: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener